# How to speed up wildcard table queries in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I ran this query:

```
SELECT
  _TABLE_SUFFIX table_id
FROM
  `mydataset.*`
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2017-12-26")
GROUP BY
  table_id
```

**Query complete (71.0s elapsed, 0 B processed)**

Here is the execution plan:

[image: BigQuery execution plan]

I've a couple of questions regarding this:

1. It's taking 70+ seconds for such a simple query, is this normal?
2. Am I doing something wrong?
3. Is there anyway the query time can be reduced?

Comment: Is this consistent, or only happened once? Most time was spent on the "wait" state

Comment: It happens every single time we execute this query across all of our datasets.

Comment: You'll have to provide a job id, since this is strange behavior. A similar query works way faster for me. Note that the query as provided doesn't run anyways.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the query while posting here. Here is the latest job id, zerocoreff:bquijob_72449f9c_16096045317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query matched 2000+ tables. It took 48 seconds to read the metadata of the storage for these tables. We can check if we can speed this up. In some sense wildcard table over partitioned tables is a temporary workaround before two-level partitioned tables are supported, where the metadata will be much smaller, 1 table vs 2000+ tables.

Comment: Do you have any idea when the "two-level partitioned tables" feature will be added?

Comment: Yes, we would also like to have the "two-level partitioned tables" functionality. Furthermore I am wondering why reading such a small amount of (meta)data would take so long? I guess this can only mean BigQuery does not have a  'central' metadata repo, right?

Comment: Q2 or Q3 is a rough estimate for two-level partitioned tables. For the metadata, storage for each table is read separately. We have some parallelism, but definitely won't spin up 2000+ threads to read them concurrently.